# Is it possible to make progress bar under two buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

Is it possible to make a `Progressbar` under two Buttons of *"water+"* and *"water -"*, Such that when I push `Button` **water+**  the `Progressbar` process one step and when I  push `Button` **water-** the `Progressbar` move a step back.

Thank you for all.

Comment: It is definitely possible in most programming languages that have such things. (what language are you using?) Please note that SO is not meant as a free coding service (see [ask]). Try to write your own implementation and if you run into problems, [edit] your question with your code (see [mcve]) and a description of the specific problem you ran into.

Comment: Hello,python,but when i place the code i can't publish my question,mybe the code is difficult.sory for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to set a `Progressbar` to **subtract** and **add** processes depending on the `Button` presses or on triggered event.

*Here is an sample code.*

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()

progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(root, length=200, maximum=10, value=5)
progressbar.grid(row=1)

process = tk.IntVar(value=5)
def add_water():
    if process.get() < progressbar['maximum']:
        process.set( process.get() + 1)
        progressbar['value'] = process.get()

def sub_water():
    if process.get() > 0:
        process.set( process.get() - 1)
        progressbar['value'] = process.get()

add = ttk.Button(root, text='Water +', command=add_water)
sub = ttk.Button(root, text='Water -', command=sub_water)

label = ttk.Label(root, textvariable=process)

label.grid(row=0)
add.grid(row=0, sticky='e')
sub.grid(row=0, sticky='w')

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: oleee,it work,congratulations,you are very good,i have one question,is it possible the indikator to start from the middle and when be move after that about 2 minutes to return alone in the middle,it is will be difficult to asure..Thank you boys for your help.

Comment: @chano: Yes, it is possible and not at all difficult but I think you should try to do it yourself and if then you have any issues with it you can ask us. Also you should accept the best answer to your questions.

Comment: ok,this code work,i insert value=5 and the indicator start from center but when push water+ the indicator go one step back.

Comment: This is, all is ok now,now if you  tell me how to make the indicator to return to the center alone after 1 minute  i will be very thankfull.

Comment: Use `after(1000, ...)` function of tkinter trigger it when you press any of the `Buttons` and it'll return the process back to centre. :) That's all I can help and stop deleting your comments.

Comment: It don't work for me,can you please insert it in your code?Thank you saad.